# How to use CSRF only on a specifc url/page in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to use CodeIngiter's CSRF mechanism. But the thing is that I do not want to use it for every url/page. I only want to use it for a specific url/page.

I have the following code. I want the CSRF check only on `site_url('login')` and `site_url('signup')`

But the CSRF happens on every page. How can I make the CSRF to ignore other URLs and only focus on the 2 I've specified above ?

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_checker';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_checker';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('home', 'about', 'licenses');
```

Comment: Why would you choose to reduce security on all your other pages?

Comment: @FrankerZ Those other pages do not accept any user input. So I just thought it wouldn't cause a security issue.

Comment: If they don't accept user input, why would CSRF even be used?

Comment: Only 2 pages are accepting user input. The login and signup page. I want only those pages to have a CSRF check. But CodeIgniter performs the CSRF check on all pages of my website viz. login, signup, home, about, licenses

Comment: But my question is: Even though CSRF may be enabled site wide, unless you're making POST requests to the server, it should never be used. So why is this an issue? Are you making POST requests on these pages? If so, why?

Comment: No I am not making POST requests on that 'static' pages, and I don't want CSRF on the entire site, only on 2 pages. That's my question. How do I achieve that?

Comment: But what I'm trying to say, is CSRF wont get executed or do anything on GET requests, for your 'static' pages. What you're trying to do, doesn't make sense. Are you actually seeing security errors, or CSRF problems on pages like home, about, and licenses?

Comment: An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: That's the error I'm getting whenever I have CSRF enabled. And I have included the CSRF hidden input element in my forms.

Comment: $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('home/(:any)', 'about', 'licenses'); Try it this way.

Comment: Thanks @KeremApaydın. Now I'm getting a problem whereby I'm getting an error whenver I make any post requests - such as when I try to login or signup

Comment: This is the error I'm getting... An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: One solution might be to roll your own Tokens library. I do this, and I like the way it works better than CodeIgniter's CSRF protection, but that's because it works exactly how I expect it to.

Comment: @KeremApaydın  An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Selected URIs can be whitelisted from csrf protection (for example API endpoints expecting externally POSTed content). You can add these URIs by editing the ‘csrf_exclude_uris’ config parameter:

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add');
```

Regular expressions are also supported (case-insensitive):

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
        'api/record/[0-9]+',
        'api/title/[a-z]+'
);
```

ref : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf